# Change one pod to framework

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile

My project use static library to integrate with third-part pods. I want to change one pod to dynamic framework. But I don't want to add use_frameworks! because this will cause all pods become dynamic framework. So is there any way to change one pod to dynamic framework and keep others the static lib (.a file)?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution, put the code at the end of your podfile

```
dynamic_frameworks = ['AFNetworking', 'OtherLibToBecomeFramework']
pre_install do |installer|
  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if dynamic_frameworks.include?(pod.name)
      puts "Overriding the build_type to dynamic_framework for #{pod.name}"
      def pod.build_type;
        Pod::BuildType.dynamic_framework
      end
    end
  end
end
```